# Is there any wireless keyboard with acceptable delay?

Tags: pc, macos, keyboard

I just got a Logitech wireless keyboard to play Worms Armageddon from to couch on the TV. I never noticed while doing other tasks but it seams that there is a delay on all the keys, what makes the supersheep unusable. I testet it with very fast typing in notepad and there is the same problem. I googled a little at it seams that all logitech wireless keyboard encounter this problem. What wireless keyboard do you recommend? (Its really important that the delay is kept to the minimum) Is it better to get a bluetooth keyboard?

*edit* well its hard to define acceptable. I just got told that a delay can be felt by a human around 10ms... So this is my guess: 
No acceptable: ±60ms
Acceptable: ±10ms

Comment: You'll have to define "acceptable".

Comment: its hard do define. It just has to feel right. But still i have tried to define it, but I'm not sure if my definition is realistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience non-bluetooth keyboards are barely good enough for typing much less games. ;-)  The Apple wireless keyboard (which is bluetooth) is good enough for Portal.  I'm waiting on L4D2 to come out to be able to test it on a proper FPS environment.

The Apple "mighty mouse" however sucks for Portal because the right click is not sensitive enough.

EDIT: After playing L4D2 on the mac for two days I can say the Mac wireless keyboard is fine for FPS games.

Comment: Totally agree, RF keyboards just won't cut it. Bluetooth keyboards generally will. I have the apple BT keyboard as well and there is no noticable lag.

Comment: i head that the apple keyboard is very good, but i definitely miss the number block :/ the mighty mouse is nice for an office environment, but i hate it for gaming :P I need a physical scroll.

Comment: The response is good.  Not having a number pad doesn't affect WASD games much.  However, I am still wrapping my mussel memory around the slightly smaller keys and their placement.

Comment: i have so much trouble paring the apple bluetooth keyboard with windows XP... :/ There is something that just would let me play Womrs Armageddon with a wireless keyboard on my mac mini :/

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that the problem is the keyboard and not the range?
Try to move from your couch near to the receiver. Do you have the same problem?

This guide from [eHow.com](http://www.ehow.com/how_2209112_improve-range-wireless-keyboard.html) could maybe help you.

Comment: i have the same problem when i sit 10cm away from the reviver :(

Answer (score 0):

I bought an EX110 / L7 wireless Logitech keyboard / mouse combo back in 2008 to play Requiem:Bloodymare. I carried it over to WoW, and used it for FPS and RTS (CS and SC) games. Been using it lately for SC2 as well. I did swap the mouse for a G5 mid 2009, but solely due to weight / comfort issues. Performance was acceptable for non competitive play.
Regards.

Comment: the thing is the distance... then more far away you are from your PC then bigger the response time. i gont my self the old apple bluetooth keyboard, its works perfectly. Event 3m away from the computer.